# Proof of Ramanujan's Identities of Euler's Function

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, gamma-function, integer-partitions, infinite-product

Consider Euler's Function defined as (and not to be confused with the totient!)

$$ \phi(x) = (1-x)(1 - x^2) (1 - x^3 ) .... =  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \left[(1 - x)^i  \right]   = (1;x)_{\infty}$$

Above are 3 different ways to notate it. Now the article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function describes special values of the given function found by ramanujan such as:

$$ \phi(e^{-\pi}) = \frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{24}}\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})}{2^{\frac{7}{8}}\pi^{\frac{3}{4}}} $$

And there are a couple more. But no link is given to their motivation/derivation. I googled around and couldn't find anything. Why are these true?

Where does even begin to retrieve the values?

Comment: Berndt and Andrews published about four books discussing the Lost Notebook and giving proofs. Go to your wikipedia page and click on Lost Notebook

Comment: This is not too important, but the notation at the end is usually written $(x;x)_\infty$ or $(x)_\infty$, not $(1;x)_\infty$.

Comment: I've written [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165359/infinite-sum-involving-ascending-powers) the standard notation. In partition analysis, $(x;x)_\infty$ is usually written shorthand as $(x)_\infty$.

Comment: I'm so silly i linked the wrong one!